# how to create a bot with in telegram with botfather and using only a code?

Tags: api, bots, telegram

There are some steps that have been mentioned in [telegram api](https://core.telegram.org/bots#3-how-do-i-create-a-bot) for creating a bot using a `botfather`.

I was hoping if there is a way that these steps can turn into code.

to be specific, I want to get a token from `botfather` using code, and then later in the code, I use this token.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very possible.

You would however need to build a Telegram Client, that will interact with BotFather.

The interaction should be easy to script, as BotFather interaction follows just a few simple steps

Comment: Can you please be little bit more specific on how am i suppose to follow the steps that are available to complete this task?

Comment: once you have a working Telegram Client, all you need to do next is send message to BotFather and parse the results

Comment: My advise would be to list all the possible bot father commands and have response path for each of the commands. This should be a straight forward thing to do. Remember, you are simply using your Telegram client to send and receive messages, nothing more than that